# Replace value of column based on value in separate column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like:

```
  ID  |   StateName   |   ZipCode
____________________________________  
  0          MD            20814     
  1                        90210   
  2          DC            20006   
  3                        05777   
  4                        12345
```

I have a function that will fill in StateName based on ZipCode value:

```
def FindZip(x):
    search = ZipcodeSearchEngine()
    zipcode = search.by_zipcode(x)
    return zipcode['State']
```

I want to fill in the blanks in the column StateName - based on the value of the corresponding ZipCode. I've unsuccessfully tried this:

```
test['StateName'] = test['StateName'].apply(lambda x: FindZip(test['Zip_To_Use']) if x == "" else x)
```

Basically, I want to apply a function to a column different from the column I am trying to change. I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: try look at `np.where`, since you did not provide any data , that is all i can do

Answer (score 2):

You can try following:

```
test['StateName'] = test.apply(lambda x: FindZip(test['Zip_To_Use']) 
                                      if x['StateName'] == "" 
                                      else x['StateName'], axis = 1)
```

The above code applies to dataframe instead of `StateName` and using `axis = 1`, applies to columns.

## Updated:

Updated with multiple condition in `if` statement (*looking at the solution below*):

```
test['StateName'] = test.apply(lambda x: FindZip(test['Zip_To_Use']) 
                                if ((x['StateName'] == "") and  (x['Zip_To_Use'] != ""))
                                else x['StateName'], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, that doesn't work as x will represent the whole series (aka pandas column) and therefore faces ambiguity when trying to figure out whether the individual cell value is "". :/

Comment: Updated with `x['StateName']`. Can you try the updated code?

Comment: Actually, it isn't working quite the way it should still. Instead of returning the appropriate state name from the function, it is returning a "None" value. When I initially said it worked, I was looking at aggregate counts of the "" (blank) value that went to zero; turns out it simply returned None. It's not the function either because the function returns the correct value when testing on a single cell! Any other ideas?

Comment: I looked at the solution below. Looks like if has two condition, can you try replacing if condition in above code with `if ((x['StateName'] == "") and  (x['Zip_To_Use'] != ""))`. Added the updated section.

Comment: It still returns "None" after including the second condition instead of a state (I spot checked by some index numbers that should return a state name after running). :/

Comment: I am not sure, I thought the updated code would return same results as code below.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a not very "pandorable" workaround. I would still love to see a more "pythonic" or "pandorable" solution if anyone has ideas! I essentially created a new list of the same length as the `DataFrame` and iterated through each row and then wrote over the column with the new list.

```
state = [FindState(test['Zip_To_Use'].iloc[i]) if (test['StateName'].iloc[i] == "" and test['Zip_To_Use'].iloc[i] != "") 
         else test['StateName'].iloc[i] for i in range(len(test))]
```

Restated in a regular for loop (for readability):

```
state = []
for i in range(len(test)):
    if (test['StateName'].iloc[i] == "" and test['Zip_To_Use'].iloc[i] != ""):
        state.append(FindState(test['Zip_To-Use'].iloc[i]))
    else:
        state.append(test['StateName'].iloc[i])
```

And then reassigned the column with this new list

```
test['StateName'] = state
```

Please let me know if you have a better solution!